# javascript tries to import a file where it is not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

I have the following directory in my project:

[image]

As you can see, `index.js` imports several components from subdirectories in `inventory`. I don't get any error with lines 1, 2, 3 and 4, but line 5 rises the following error:

[image]

I don't know why it looks for it in `./Chips/chips`, and not just in `./Chips`, like line 3, that is the same case.

**EDIT**
By the way, I had some issues when connecting my local repository to a previously existing remote repository. Subdirectories inside `inventory` where lowercased, so I got an error because the compiler couldn't locate the uppercased directorie, so I uppercased them by hand, and I got this error.

Comment: Is your component correctly exported in the `/Chips/index.js`?

Comment: have you tried restarting npm?

Comment: @BillMetcalf Yes, in fact, everything is running without any problem in other computers. Please check my edit.

Comment: Can you show us what is inside `/Chips/index.js`? I am assume your are doing a default export?

Comment: @Qiarash That was it, I was missing to restart it. Thanks four your time, gentlemen

Comment: happy to help :)